# How to have Spring Webflux Websocket route as annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

Question regarding how to have Spring Webflux Websocket as annotation please.

I am working on a Springboot Webflux Websocket project where it handles BOTH restful api AND a websocket.

To emphasize, it is a Spring Webflux project alone. Not a Springboot starter websocket, not a Springboot rsocket, not a Springboot pub sub.

The project is as follow:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EchoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EchoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
public class EchoController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/getEcho")
    public Mono<String> getEcho() {
        return Mono.just("echo");
    }
}

public class EchoHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        return session.send( session.receive().map(msg -> "RECEIVED ON SERVER :: " + msg.getPayloadAsText()).map(session::textMessage));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class EchoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EchoHandler echoHandler() {
        return new EchoHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/echo", echoHandler());
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
        mapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter(webSocketService());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
        return new HandshakeWebSocketService(new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy());
    }

}

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

As you can see, in this project, there is the "traditional" annotation @GetMapping(value = "/getEcho"). Many Spring projects uses this style where it is exposed as annotation (event rscocket, pub/sub, etc...)

How to have:

```
 @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/echo", echoHandler());
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
```

as annotation, some kind of @WebsocketMapping("/echo") which will help present an unified and cleaner way to see routes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Team, this is not currently supported, neither have plan to support route based web socket for Webflux.